# .ENCODING international chars (hebrew,thai,russian,chinese,....)

Tags: encoding, utf-8, wget, hebrew, iconv

international html files archived by **wget** 
should contain chars like this

(example hebrew and thai:)
**אב
הם**
and **ยคน**

instead they are saved like this:
**íäáåãéú** and **ÃÒ¡à§é**

How to get the these displayed properly?

iconv filename.html
**iconv: illegal input sequence at position 1254**

**SOLVED**:  There was nothing wrong.
Only i didnt notice the default  **php.ini** did set the charset in the http header but
to use various charsets like this  *meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-874"* you needed to set:    **default_charset = "empty";**
....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages aren't "saved like this", whatever you're using to view the file is simply interpreting the encoding incorrectly. To know what encoding the file is in you should have paid attention to the HTTP `Content-Type` header during download; that's gone now.
Your only other chance is to parse the equivalent HTML meta tag in the `<head>`, *if the document has one*.

Otherwise, you can only *guess* the encoding of the document.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for more required background knowledge.